# How to create a new variable with values depending on another variable containing specific words?

Tags: r

I have this dataset with information on a bunch of articles:

```
ID number, Header, Rubric, Article Text, Date.
```

I would like to sort the articles based on content, i.e. I would like to create a new variable using an "if" statement:

- "if" the variable 'Article Text' contains the string 'Second World War'  "then" 'New Variable'= 1 and
- "if" the variable 'Article Text' contains the word 'Syria' "then" 'New Variable'= 2.
- Hereafter I want to create new datasets depending on the value of 'New Variable'.

I would like to be able to try out different methods to see what works the better/gives me the more correct sorting of the aricles - like conditioning on

- one word
- several words around same topic (all in text)
- several words around same topic (one or more in text)
- a word string

So what I am asking for is help to understand the basic setup I need to create, to be able to use different very simple text analysis tools to sort my dataset.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First i reccomend using serveral logical variables for each string you search for, since articles may contain more than one of the strings.

Second, in what form do you have the dataset? Do you read it from a file or a database, or do you have it as a data.frame or a list...

Comment: Thank you very much. You are definitely right, the articles may contain more of the strings. I have the data as a dataframe in R.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal Example would be this:

```
# An example data.frame containing some combinations of letters:
data <- data.frame(a=paste0(LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[3:5]))

# Replace this with the strings you want to search for:
strings <- c("A", "C")
# And this with the names for the new columns:
names(strings) <- c("colA", "colB")

# Search for the strings and create new columns, replace $a according to your column-names:
data <- cbind(data, data.frame(lapply(strings, grepl, data$a)))
```

What this does:

`grepl` searches for the pattern defined in the first argument in the character-vector in the second argument and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the pattern matched or not.

`lapply` applies the function in the second argument to all the elements of the list in the first element and uses all further agruments as additional agruments to the function in the second arguemnt. Lapply returns a list.

`as.data.frame` makes a `data.frame` out of the list.

`cbind` finally does a column-bind of the new dataframe to the old one.

As alsways, run the Code line by line and output intermediate values and look at the help-entries of the used functions.